# Spring Show Empty Page When Entering GET Url

Tags: spring

I have a request map which returns list from database in json. Is it possible if visitor enters the exact url in browser, the page will be empty?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pics/{profileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<ProfilePic> getProfilePics(@PathVariable("profileId") BigInteger profileId) {
    return practiceServices.getProfilePics(profileId);
}
```

if visitor enters the url `http://localhost:8080/practiceProject/pics/10`, the page will show the list, but I don't want visitors to see it. I want the browser to show an empty page. Is it possible?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the code you show.  This 'server' side code returns the List but it's up to your client to decide what to do with it.

Comment: I am using this url in order to get pictures with Ajax. That's why if user tries to enter this url, then the browser should show an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick solution check a header that will be sent within your AJAX requests. If this is not available just return `null` or whatever. You can also return a `ResponseEntity<List<ProfilePic>>` and in case the header is not present respond with a different HTTP status or just with an empty body or 204 (no content) using the `ResponseEntity` static methods / builder.

For example you can check if the header `X-Requested-With` is available with the value `XMLHttpRequest`. That is one of the default headers that will be sent when AJAX is used (but not always; I don't know exactly when it is sent and when not - maybe it depends on the used javascript library).

But keep in mind: This is nothing secure, someone can fake those headers and access the page anyway.

If you want such a behaviour for your complete API try it within a filter which checks this header and if available proceed with `doFilter`, otherwise stop and respond nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the list on body of request, if you don't like to do it you should create a ModelAndView object and add the object list to it.

Example:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/pics/{profileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")

public ModelAndView getProfilePics(@PathVariable("profileId") BigInteger profileId) {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("html_to_be_returned");
    view.addObject("list", practiceServices.getProfilePics(profileId));
    return view 
}'

PS: I have not test this code so it can have same issue.`